# Download as PDF

Tags: visualforce, blob.topdf

In below code i have got the content in PDF i have to download it into PDF to my system instead of downloading it into salesforce.

```
public class OrderPDF 
{
    public Order orderRecord{get; set;}         
    @auraEnabled    
    public static void SetRecordId(String OrderRecId)
    {               
        PageReference pageRef= new PageReference('/apex/myorderexcel');
        pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',OrderRecId);
        Blob pdfContent = pageRef.getContentAsPDF();
        system.debug('pdfContent'+pdfContent);        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer the results back to the client, then initiate a download.

```
// client code
let action = component.get("c.orderRecord");
action.setParams({ OrderRecId: recordId });
action.setCallback(this, result => {
  if(result.getState() === 'SUCCESS') {
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.download = 'example.pdf';
    downloadLink.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+result.getReturnValue();
    downloadLink.click();
  } else {
    // show an error
  }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

---

```
// Server code
@AuraEnabled
public static String SetRecordId(String OrderRecId) {               
    PageReference pageRef= Page.myorderexcel;
    pageRef.getParameters().put('Id',OrderRecId);
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pageRef.getContentAsPDF());
}
```

You'll want to read more about [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: thanks dude @sfdcfox